# Subquery returned more than 1 value sql query error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following code . I am getting `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`
 from this query. please have a look on query written below.

```
SELECT X.ITEMCODE,
       X.[ITEM_DESCRIPTION],
       X.[Received],
       X.[Issues],
       X.[Project]
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        T0.ItemCode AS ITEMCODE,
        T0.ItemName AS [ITEM_DESCRIPTION],
        ISNULL((
            SELECT SUM(T1.[Quantity])
            FROM IGN1 T1
            WHERE T1.[DocDate] BETWEEN '1march2015' AND '1march2015'
                AND T1.WhsCode = 'RecBay'
                AND T1.[ItemCode] = T0.[ItemCode]
        ), 0) AS [Received],
        ISNULL((
            SELECT T1.[Project]
            FROM IGN1 T1
            WHERE T1.[DocDate] BETWEEN '1march2015' AND '1march2015'
                AND T1.WhsCode = 'RecBay'
                AND T1.[ItemCode] = T0.[ItemCode]
        ), 0) AS [Project],
        ISNULL((
            SELECT SUM(CAST(T1.[Quantity] AS INT))
            FROM IGE1 T1
            WHERE T1.DocDate BETWEEN '1march2015' AND '1march2015'
                AND T1.WhsCode = 'RecBay'
                AND T1.[ItemCode] = T0.[ItemCode]
        ), 0) AS [Issues]

    FROM OITM T0
) X
```

Comment: `ISNULL((SELECT T1.[Project] FROM IGN1 ...` returns more than one row.

Comment: One or more of the inner queries are returning the wrong number of rows.

Comment: what should be query then? make changes and post query here again please.

Comment: How should we know? It's your tables and your data. We need lots of more info...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the below query and let me know what error you getting:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        T0.ItemCode AS ItemCode,
        ISNULL(SUM(T1.[Quantity]),0) AS Received,
        ISNULL(T1.[Project], '') AS Project,
        SUM(CAST(T1.[Quantity] AS INT)) AS Issues
    FROM OITM T0
    LEFT JOIN IGN1 T1 ON T1.[ItemCode] = T0.[ItemCode]
    WHERE T1.[DocDate] BETWEEN '1march2015' AND '1march2015'
        AND T1.WhsCode = 'RecBay'
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    T0.ItemCode AS ITEMCODE,
    T0.ItemName AS [ITEM_DESCRIPTION],
    T1.*
FROM OITM T0
LEFT JOIN CTE T1 ON T1.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this -

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    T0.ItemCode AS ITEMCODE,
    T0.ItemName AS [ITEM_DESCRIPTION],
    ISNULL([Received], 0) AS [Received],
    ISNULL([Project], '') AS [Project],
    ISNULL([Issues], 0) AS [Issues]
FROM OITM T0
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
          [Issues] = SUM(CAST(T1.[Quantity] AS INT))
        , [Received] = SUM(T1.[Quantity])
        , [Project] = MAX(T1.[Project])
    FROM IGN1 T1
    WHERE T1.[DocDate] BETWEEN '1march2015' AND '1march2015'
        AND T1.WhsCode = 'RecBay'
        AND T1.[ItemCode] = T0.[ItemCode]
) T1
```

and provide a small example of your dataset

Comment: the error is coming when i add Project like ISNULL((
            SELECT T1.[Project]
            FROM IGN1 T1
            WHERE T1.[DocDate] BETWEEN '1march2015' AND '1march2015'
                AND T1.WhsCode = 'RecBay'
                AND T1.[ItemCode] = T0.[ItemCode]
        ), 0) AS [Project],  I am not getting how should it be. when i removed this field .then result coming up.but i want this field. please help in this.

Comment: This project is nvarchar

Answer (score 0):

I can get some information from your query and i can tell that the OITM's Item Code is not 1 to 1 relate to IGN1's Project. that's the reason of your error, and the problem is what kind of result you want it be.
i can do things like this:

```
    ======================================================
    ItemCode   ItemName   Received    Project    Issues  
    ======================================================
      1           a          c        Unknown     1008
      1           a          c        Unknown1    1008
      1           a          c        Unknown2    1087
```

if this is what you want you can just turn your sub query to left join

```
    select T0.ItemCode,
           T0.ItemName,
           ISNULL(T1.Received,0)as Received,
           ISNULL(T1.Project,0)as Project,
           ISNULL(T1.Issues,0)as Issues
      from (select distinct ItemCode,ItemName from OITM) T0
      left join IGN1 T1 on T1.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode
       where T1.[DocDate] BETWEEN '1march2015' AND '1march2015'
        AND T1.WhsCode = 'RecBay'
```